# regular expression to capture the folder name with specfic structure

Tags: linux, bash, shell, grep, regular-expression

what is the regular expression to capture the folder name with this structure

x.x.x.x-x  ( x - integer number )

```
 ls /usr/hdp | .....
 2.6.0.3-8  current HG_MASTER 2.4.3 34.1 45-995
```

expected output

```
2.6.0.3-8



ls -lh /usr/hdp/
total 8.0K
drwxr-xr-x. 27 root root 4.0K Jan  1 15:24 2.6.0.3-8
```

Comment: As is traditional, http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs is usually linked to about now.

Comment: and [Don't Parse ls](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls)

Comment: so what is your solution , if you not want to capture it with ls ?

Comment: both of the links above offer several alternatives.  e.g. `find` with either a `-name` or `-regex` predicate (or the case-insensitive `-iname` and `-iregex`).

Comment: cas please send your solution as answer

Comment: `x.x.x.x-x` can `x` be more than one digit?

Comment: yes - it can be

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you tagged [bash](/questions/tagged/bash), you can actually do this with the shell's filename matching, using extended globs:

```
$ shopt -s extglob
$ touch /some/path/{2.6.0.3-8,22.66.0.333-8,foobar}
$ printf "%s\n" /some/path/+([0-9]).+([0-9]).+([0-9]).+([0-9])-+([0-9])
/some/path/22.66.0.333-8
/some/path/2.6.0.3-8
```

The pattern there works like more common things like `*` or `*.png`, so you can just stick the fixed parts like paths in it. Add a trailing slash `/` to only match directories. (the slash does appear in the output too, though.)

In ERE regex, the pattern is the same as `[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+-[0-9]+`. A fuzzier version would just check for the allowed characters, like `+([-.0-9])` (or `[-.0-9]+` in ERE), but that of course would also match e.g. `123..456`.

If you want to just print the filenames, `find` might be easier, but if you want to run a command on them, then a shell loop is also an option (along with `find -exec`).

Comment: nice but how to do it when I am from other folder for example , I am in /tmp and want to capture the folder from /usr/hdp/

Comment: OP mentioned matching directories.. but that should be okay if no filenames match.. :)

Comment: @jango, just stick the path in the front, as with `*`

Comment: @Sundeep, ah, true. But you can add the trailing slash to only match directories.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `find` instead. For exact match use pattern:

```
find /usr/hdp -regextype sed -regex "\/usr\/hdp\/[0-9]*\.[0-9]*\.[0-9]*\.[0-9]*-[0-9]*"
```

If you need any files with only *digits*, `.` and `-` symbols in names try:

```
find /usr/hdp -regextype sed -regex "\/usr\/hdp\/[.0-9-]*"
```

Comment: not works on both way

Comment: under /usr/hdp/    , we have 
2.6.4.0-91

Comment: @jango, you did't say that filename can contain several digits consistently

Comment: @jango, can file contain other symbols? Can you complete your post with output of command `ls -lh`?

Comment: updated  , see mu question again please

Comment: so can you please update the answer ?

Comment: Updated earlier. Works fine with GNU find 4.7.0

Comment: close, but that won't actually work.  you're running `find /usr/udp` but the pattern you're searching for starts with `./`.  I expect you tested with `find .`.  either use `/usr/hdp/` at the start of the search pattern, or use `.*/`.

Comment: @cas, i edited my answer. Thank you very much! It's my mistake, i missed it in my test lab. I was looking for files in current directory with `find .` and forgot to replace.

Answer (score 1):

```
find . -type d -regextype posix-egrep -regex '^./([0-9]+[.]){3}[0-9]+[-][0-9]+'
```

Use find and then the regextype flag to set the reg expression syntax to egrep. Use -regex to check against 3 digits and a "dot" and then a digit a "dash" and a digit.

If the digits are more than one character, you will need + after each digit.

Comment: why - f   ( this is folder )

Comment: Yeah sorry. It's a directory and so should be d and not f for file. I will change.

Comment: also the same your syntax not capture the folder - 2.6.4.0-91

Comment: You will need to add + to each [0-9] to signify 1 or more digits between 0 and 9. I have amended my solution

Comment: so can you please update the answer ?

Comment: I have. That's what I said in my last sentence

Answer (score -1):

```
ls /usr/hdp | egrep '[0-9]+.[0-9]+.[0-9]+.[0-9]+-[0-9]+'
```